# How to iterate through String List of Dictionaries?

Tags: c#, oracle, list, dictionary

I have the below code. I have an Oracle query which returns multiple rows. I need to fill the data into dictionaries list but I have a problem which is the list is always filled with the last row duplicated. How to iterate the list with each Oracle row.

The code :

```
 var list = new List<string>();

 List<Dictionary<String, String>> listDic = new List<Dictionary<String, String>>();

        using (var con = new OracleConnection(Config.EDLRDev))
        {
            var com = con.CreateCommand();
            try
            {
                con.Open();
                com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM edlr_comm_rep_total a where a.dealer_id = 'wb-pos00289' and a.comm_type = 'Activation' ";

                //com.Parameters.Add("msisdn", OracleDbType.Char).Value = msisdn;
                Dictionary<String, String> objDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();

                var reader = com.ExecuteReader();
                if (reader.HasRows)
                {
                    while (reader.Read())
                    {
                        string CommissionDealerId = reader[0].ToString();
                        string Month = reader[1].ToString();
                        string DealerCommissionType = reader[2].ToString();
                        string CommissionCount = reader[3].ToString();
                        string CommissionAmount = reader[4].ToString();
                        objDic["CommissionDealerId"] = CommissionDealerId;
                        objDic["Month"] = Month;
                        objDic["DealerCommissionType"] = DealerCommissionType;
                        objDic["CommissionCount"] = CommissionCount;
                        objDic["CommissionAmount"] = CommissionAmount;
                        listDic.Add(objDic);
                    }
                }

                reader.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {

                con.Dispose();

            }
            con.Dispose();

            return listDic;


        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the same Dictionary `objDic` which was instantiated outside your while loop. You are just replacing the value of the dictionary each pass over the loop. In your list you are adding a reference to the same objDic dictionary, that is why you have duplicates. You need to create a new dictionary in each pass over within your while loop.

```
try
        {
            con.Open();
            com.CommandText = "SELECT * FROM edlr_comm_rep_total a where a.dealer_id = 'wb-pos00289' and a.comm_type = 'Activation' ";

            //com.Parameters.Add("msisdn", OracleDbType.Char).Value = msisdn;


            var reader = com.ExecuteReader();
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    Dictionary<String, String> objDic = new Dictionary<string, string>();
                    string CommissionDealerId = reader[0].ToString();
                    string Month = reader[1].ToString();
                    string DealerCommissionType = reader[2].ToString();
                    string CommissionCount = reader[3].ToString();
                    string CommissionAmount = reader[4].ToString();
                    objDic["CommissionDealerId"] = CommissionDealerId;
                    objDic["Month"] = Month;
                    objDic["DealerCommissionType"] = DealerCommissionType;
                    objDic["CommissionCount"] = CommissionCount;
                    objDic["CommissionAmount"] = CommissionAmount;
                    listDic.Add(objDic);
                }
            }

            reader.Close();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to initialize `objDic` inside the loop:

```
var reader = com.ExecuteReader();
if (reader.HasRows) {
    while (reader.Read()) {
        Dictionary<String, String> objDic = new Dictionary<string, string>(); // MOVED!
        string CommissionDealerId = reader[0].ToString();
        string Month = reader[1].ToString();
        string DealerCommissionType = reader[2].ToString();
        string CommissionCount = reader[3].ToString();
        string CommissionAmount = reader[4].ToString();
        objDic["CommissionDealerId"] = CommissionDealerId;
        objDic["Month"] = Month;
        objDic["DealerCommissionType"] = DealerCommissionType;
        objDic["CommissionCount"] = CommissionCount;
        objDic["CommissionAmount"] = CommissionAmount;
        listDic.Add(objDic);
    }
}
```

Otherwise you are just changing the same instance all over again.